# Zend Framework Session Namespace debugging print_r or equivalent

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

Working with Zend, and the Sessions Namespace, trying to debug an issue I am running where I think something should be set, but it appears that it isn't so I'd like to find a means of seeing the whole namespace object but when I try `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on it, all I get is

```
Zend_Session_Namespace Object ( [_namespace:protected] => msp )
```

So I am wondering cause I can't find anything anywhere else on the subject currently is there a means of viewing that object? Is there a debug method that I can enable/disable for it through zend somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily debug it as

```
print_r($_SESSION) or print_r($_SESSION['YourNameSpace']) or
print_r(Zend_Session::namespaceGet('YourNameSpace'));
```

Since whenever we try to set property on zend_session_namespace object,thats what it does 
internally

```
 $_SESSION[$this->_namespace][$name] = $value;
```

Where $name refer to the property we are trying to set with vale $value.